# Bounding $c_1c_2...c_k$ if $c_1+c_2+...+c_k<=n$ and $c_i\geq 0$.

Tags: inequality, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

As the question asks, given $k\leq n$, and $c_i\geq 0$, is there a way to know the upper bound of $c_1c_2...c_k$ knowing that $c_1+c_2+...+c_k<=n$. I was thinking about the AM-GM inequality but it bounds $c_1c_2...c_k$ from below instead of up. Any help?

Comment: The A.M-G.M inequality will result in an **upper** bound on $c_1 \cdot c_2 \cdots c_k$.

Comment: No, AM-GM gives an upper bound on the product. The lower bound is zero, because you can choose one of the summands to be zero.